# Repeat alarm not working at exact 15 minutes interval in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Hi I have created one alarm at exact 15 minutes interval after that based on exact alarm i am creating one repeating with 15 minutes alarm but the repeating alarm  not working exactly.

//Calculate exact 15 minutes interval

```
public static long calculateInterval() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(getCurrentTimeIn24Hrs().split(":")[0]));
        alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(getCurrentTimeIn24Hrs().split(":")[1]));
        alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long start = alarm.getTimeInMillis();
        long remain = 0;
        if (m < 15) {
            remain = 15 - m;
        } else if (m < 30) {
            remain = 30 - m;
        } else if (m < 45) {
            remain = 45 - m;
        } else {
            remain = 60 - m;
        }
        remain = start + remain * 60 * 1000;
        return remain;
    }

public void setAlarm() {
        Log.i("Service++++", "Alarm set");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, SetAlarm.class);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1234, myIntent, 0);
        int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            am.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, Utility.calculateInterval(), pendingIntent);
        else
            am.set(ALARM_TYPE, Utility.calculateInterval(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

// Repeating Alarm

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(mContext, UpdateServiceAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1236, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: not getting you correctly. Inside one alarm that is fired at 15 min regular interval you are setting another alarm that is also repeating at 15 min interval ?

Comment: @Radhey First alarm i am calculating next exact 15 minutes based on that i  am creating repeating alarm for every 15 minutes interval

Comment: why you are calculating #exact 15 min like this ! just set 15 min interval as per the milli sec. thats it .and after completion  15 min of first alarm which is regular in interval ,that also update your 2nd alarm which you created .

Comment: No alarm should be fire on exact 15 minutes for example 10:00,10:15,10:30 etc.,

Comment: No issue in first alarm. Repeating alarm is the problem

Comment: just do rough work in your note . if i set 1st alarm at 15 min it will fire 2nd alarm which is also in 15min interval ,now think when your 2nd alarm is started , your 1st alarm (which is repeating ) also started . this way your first alarm will change value of you 2nd one before 2nd one is getting fired. make sense !

Comment: First alarm is not a repeating alarm second one is repeating

Comment: to cross verify this , just set 2nd alarm interval value to 10 min . and check it again ,weather 2nd one will fire or not!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140024/discussion-between-radhey-and-shan).

Answer (score 0):

You set inexact alarm. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) :

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

So use `alarmManager.setExact()` like your first alarm and restart  each 15 minutes.

Comment: alarmManager.setExact() this will repeat automatically every 15 minutes or i need to start again?

Comment: @Shan No. You catch intent from alarm and restart it( each 15 minutes).